# Inserting query parameters into DynamoDB using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to have my server less function working as i am trying my hands on it.

I am trying to perform API PUT method , which will be integrated with proxy lambda function

I have a lambda function  as below:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    param = event['queryStringParameters']
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
    table = dynamodb.Table('*****')
    
          
    response = table.put_item(
        Item = {



        }
        
    )
```

i want to insert the Param value which i am getting from query parameters into DynamoDB table.

I am able to achieve it by :

```
response = table.put_item(
            Item = param 
)
```

But the issue here is if the partition key is present it will just over ride the value in place of throwing an error of present partition key.

I know the PUT method is idempotent.

Is there any other way i can achieve this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why this is an issue in your case: _the issue here is if the partition key is present it will just over ride the value in place of throwing an error of present partition key_

Comment: @Shawn . 
I am want partition key to be unique for each insert. If there an attempt to insert a new record with same partition key. Then i have to have a case for that to throw an error stating partition key is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item, you can:

> "perform a conditional put operation (add a new item if one with the
> specified primary key doesn't exist)"
>
> **Note**
>
> To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a
> conditional expression that contains the attribute_not_exists function
> with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the
> table. Since every record must contain that attribute, the
> attribute_not_exists function will only succeed if no matching item
> exists.

Also see [DynamoDB: updateItem only if it already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538754/dynamodb-updateitem-only-if-it-already-exists)

If you really need to know whether the item exists or not so you can trigger your exception logic, then run a query first to see if the item already exists and don't even call `put_item`.  You can also explore whether using a combination of ConditionExpression and one of the ReturnValues options (for put_item or update_item) may return enough data for you to know if an item existed.